# jQuery Form file upload check file on server and generate errors to pass to the client

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am using jQuery.Form to upload files on server.
Here is an sample I am using http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

I wan to to validate file on server for NULL and for extension,

```
public FileUploadJsonResult UploadSubscriptions(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file == null)
                return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = string.Format(" Error uploading file. Choose the file") } }; 

            if(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() != "csv")
                return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = string.Format("{0} Error uploading file. Invalid extension.", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)) } }; 

            //Doing the thing here...

            return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = string.Format("{0} uploaded successfully.", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)) } }; 
        }
```

but in all of the cases if i will return FileUploadJsonResult  on client it will be successful result, function `success` will be executed:

```
success: function (result) {
                //debugger;
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, result.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, 'Error uploading file. Try again later');

                $('div.growlUI').css("background", "url(attention48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px");
            }
```

In such case i may edit the function 'success' to put conditions to check result.message and then display growlUI with error, but i would rather generate error on server to execute client function `error`
How can i do that?

**UPDATE:**

here is my 'success' funciton modification to handle errors:

```
success: function (result) {
                //debugger;
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();

                $.growlUI(null, result.message);

                if (result.message.indexOf("Error") != -1)
                    $('div.growlUI').css("background", "url(attention48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px");
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Success` and `error` refer to the call you make to the server. An error is if the addres is unreachable or there are connection problems, it's not related to the logic of your application. You should handle errors in the flow of your application (like a not allowed extension) with conditional messages and behaviours in the success function, because there were no problem in the call itself. At least that's what i think.