# jQuery Form file upload Files with size greater thatn 4MB filed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am using jQuery Form upload. I am unable to upload file with the size more than 4MB I debug my request in Fiddler and it is saying 
`ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.`

If i am uploading small file all working well and I do not get any error.

You can see my code here: [jQuery Form file upload check file on server and generate errors to pass to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640230/jquery-form-file-upload-check-file-on-server-and-generate-errors-to-pass-to-the-c)

Any ideas how to fix that? Any thoughts why it is happens?

Also I think i would add some code on client which would check the file size before submit on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to increase the [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) setting in web.config.

More useful info here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to check file size on beforeSubmit?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to see file size until the request is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have problems with the max size you can upload with POST. Web server limit the size of the files you can upload. I don't know anything of ASP.NET but i found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1048294.aspx/1?Maximum%20Image%20upload%20size) article that might help you (the articol says that max post size is 4 Mb)

Comment: Is it possible to check file size on beforeSubmit?

Comment: No i don't think that's possible. It's a check you have to make server side.